# "OAuthException: (#100) Invalid parameter" by creating an event

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i try to create a facebook event with the open graph and the php sdk.

i use this code:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXX', 
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX', 
        'cookie' => true // enable optional cookie support
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

$event_start = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);


if ($user) {
  try {
    $event = $facebook->api("/me/events","post",array(
      'title'=>'My Event Name',
      'start_time'=>$event_start
      // etc add your other event info here
    ));
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo($e);
  }
}
```

i have this permissions: create_event,rsvp_event

and i get this error:

**OAuthException: (#100) Invalid parameter**

how can i solve the problem?

Comment: I think you might need to use PROFILE_ID/events and not me/events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events

Comment: i tried this:  
  
`...  
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');  
    $id = $user_profile['id'];  
    $event = $facebook->api("/".$id."/events","post",array(   
    ....`  
  
but i doesn't work  
  
i think, /me/events is correct like in this facebook tutorial:   http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/560/

Answer (score 1):

i found the problem... i used "title" instead of "name"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

My solution was to format the 'start_time' correctly to [ISO 8601](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

For example 01.12.2012 13:45 in CET would be

```
2012-12-01T13:45:00+0100
```

I didn't find that solution anywhere so far. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone want to know better, here is the fb page with details related to Event.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

`title` should be the parameter for the name of the event.

Comment: Downvote without comment? I posted this answer because that may clear up the future readers.